# How to Install Ubuntu on hybrid drive, if windows is already there In my hdd

Tags: boot, dual-boot, format, sshd, hybrid-efi

The thing is I want only ubuntu on my pc, my hdd had windows already Installed
I have brought new ssd, now my question is

***1. How to format hdd which contain windows 10
2. How to install Ubuntu on my hybrid drive setup.***

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "hybrid drive"? You can install to SSD and use the HDD for storage for example.

Comment: do you want to move windows to ssd and ubuntu to hdd? or do you want ubuntu on both. i have a 'hybrid drive setup' myself, i keep / (root) on sdd and /home on hdd. go with that in the custom partitioning.

Comment: i want ubuntu on both and i want to delete windows that is on hdd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options for installing Ubuntu on your PC.

1. Select the *Erase Disk and install Ubuntu* option from the *Installation type* screen of the Ubuntu installer. This will install everything on the SSD if you select the SSD as the installation target. After booting to Ubuntu for the first time you can format the HDD as ext4 and use it for storage.
2. The 2nd option is to install `/` (root) on the SSD and `/home` on the HDD.

   At the *Installation type* screen of the Ubuntu installer select the *Something else* option to do [manual partitioning](https://askubuntu.com/q/343268) and install `/` on the SSD and `/home` on the HDD. New installations of Ubuntu create a swap file in */* by default instead of a swap partition.

[image: Installation type]